# Bash script to copy files and then move to trash (non-destructive)

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, rsync, backup

I am trying to write a bash script to copy files with cp or, preferably, rsync and then move the source files to the trash. I do not want to use mv because in case of an error, I want to be able to recover the source files.

This script works. It hard codes the destination folder.

```
for i in "$@"; do
    cp -a -R "$i" '/home/userxyz/Downloads/folder1'
    gio trash "$i"
done
```

However, this script that uses a variable for the destination folder does not work.

```
read -p "Enter destination folder: " destination

for i in "$@"; do
    cp -a -R "$i" "$destination"
    gio trash "$i"
done
```

Error when I enter '/home/userxyz/Downloads/folder1' as destination:

```
cp: cannot create regular file "'/home/userxyz/Downloads/folder1'": No such file or directory
```

Similarly, this works:

```
for i in "$@"; do
    rsync "$i" '/home/userxyz/Downloads/folder1'
    gio trash "$i"
done
```

But this does not work:

```
read -p "Enter destination folder: " destination

for i in "$@"; do
    rsync "$i" "$destination"
    gio trash "$i"
done
```

Error:

```
rsync: change_dir#3 "/home/userxyz//'/home/userxyz/Downloads" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(720) [Receiver=3.1.3]
```

I have confirmed that '/home/userxyz/Downloads/folder1' exists. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be including quotes when entering the destination name. If so, leave them out. If not, add `set -x` to the script to see what's going on there.

Comment: `cp -a` includes `-R`, so you don't need that option (and `rsync` also has an `-a` / `--archive` option). You also don't need that loop, replace `"$i"` with `"$@"`.

Comment: @berndbausch Thank you very much! Leaving out the quotes solved my problem.

Comment: @Freddy Thank you for your suggestion. I removed the loop and changed the rsync/cp options per your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your helpful suggestions, @berndbausch and @Freddy! It turns out that the single quotes in the destination name were the problem. I modified the script to remove the single quotes and also remove the unnecessary loop. It now works with both rsync and cp.

```
read -p "Enter destination folder: " destination

dest="${destination%\'}" #remove the suffix ' (escaped with a backslash to prevent shell interpretation)
dest="${dest#\'}" #remove prefix ' (escaped with a backslash to prevent shell interpretation)

rsync -a -W "$@" $dest #or cp -a "$@" $dest
gio trash "$@"
```

Comment: Better still, don't provide the single quotes in the first place. No other utility expects them